# The server tag is not well formed, gridview not fit to screen

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I'm having this server tag is not well formed problem when i added this code Width="100%" into my source of my aspx file. My gridview is not fitting to page. Hence, the Width="100%" was one of the sol given by the internet to fit it into screen size. however it doesn't seem to work. I also attempt this css tag,  and added it into my the necessary code into the css file but it doesnt seem to be fitted to screen.

Here are my codes

ASPX source code :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<ul id="info">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" BackColor="#CCCCCC"     BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" DataKeyNames="caseid"     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="caseid" HeaderText="caseid" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="caseid" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fullname" HeaderText="fullname" SortExpression="fullname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="contact" HeaderText="contact" SortExpression="contact" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="typeofcrime" HeaderText="typeofcrime" SortExpression="typeofcrime" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="location" HeaderText="location" SortExpression="location" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="datetime" HeaderText="datetime" SortExpression="datetime" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="citizenreport" HeaderText="citizenreport" SortExpression="citizenreport" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
</asp:GridView>
</ul>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$     ConnectionStrings:projectConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [caseid], [fullname], [contact], [typeofcrime],         [location], [datetime], [citizenreport], [picture] FROM [Report]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

CSS file :

```
#info
{
    width:100%;
}
```

MasterPage file :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Admin.master.cs" Inherits="AdminWebApp.Admin" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-->
var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "image/s1.jpg"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "image/s2.jpg"
var image3 = new Image()
image3.src = "image/s3.jpg"
var image4 = new Image()
image4.src = "image/s4.jpg"
var image5 = new Image()
image5.src = "image/s5.jpg"
//-->
</script>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<title>iPolice</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />

<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <script src ="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta2)/IE8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->    
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<ul id="Slideshow">
<img src="image/s1.jpg" name="slide" width="1025px" height="250px">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var step = 1
function slideit() {
    document.images.slide.src = eval("image" + step + ".src")
    if (step < 5)
        step++
    else
        step = 1
    setTimeout("slideit()", 2500)
}
slideit()
//-->
</script>
</ul>

<%-- <input type="image" id="header" style="height:250px;width:1148px;" src="image/header.jpg" /> --%>
<input type="image" id="myimage" style="height:53px;width:200px;" src="image/logo.jpg" >

<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Recent cases</a></li>   
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>      
</ul>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>    
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>

    <div style="left: 0%; width: 1150px; position: absolute; top:80%; height: 800px;">

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

</form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have a `ul` wrapping the `GridView`? This is invalid HTML markup.

Comment: @TimBJames correct, and also try `#GridView1{width:100%;}`

Comment: @DiederikEEn I would avoid using Id's for .Net controls just because of their dynamic nature.

Comment: To TIM :  I'm new in using html5 with c# to develop my webapp. I have a ul markup for my master page which i used html5 to develop it. and i adjusted some of the position using the ul markup and link it with my css file. The aspx file didnt prompt me any error at the gridview, so i didnt know its invalid

TO DiederikEEn : the code you given are meant to be placed in my CSS file? If yes it doesn't seems to work :/

Comment: removed and the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.GridView    
{    
  width: 100%;    
  table-layout: fixed;    
}
```

Comment: You will need to add `CssClass="GridView"` to your control to use this css class.

Comment: I have done it already :(
If i have not mistaken the .gridview code should be placed in my css file. Unfortunately, my gridview seems to be exceeding the size of my image slideshow header.

Comment: I would recommend create a new page, put your gridview in there. But just the gridview. Use CssClass="GridView" and the css I wrote before. It should work, also don't forget to remove width attribute from your gridview. This should solve what you've asked. Further you can add other components and inspect what causes your actual problem.